# Google Directions response to Google Map URL?

Tags: c#, google-maps-api-3, google-directions-api

I am using C# to use the Google Web Services - Directions API. 
Can I use the DirectionsResponse and convert that to
a Google URL? 
Can I then copy it into a web browser to display the result?